# Is it possible to include functions as javascript constructor parameters?

Tags: javascript, constructor, functional-programming

When I try to pass an anonymous function as a parameter the Cache function, I get the following message:

> TypeError: Illegal constructor at TypeError (native)

Example:

```
var x = new Cache(function(test) {
    return test;
});
```

Is it possible to pass anonymous functions to constructors?

Comment: Like `new Foo(function () {})`? Sure it is. Show your code that produces this error.

Comment: You would see that if you were trying to call the constructor of something native e.g.  `new HTMLElement(anything)` note the explicit error message is telling you its illegal, which means it knows what *is* legal (if anything) which means its not user code.

Comment: I made a mistake - was calling a javascript core function - not a standard constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the use of a reserved function name (`Cache`). The solution is to use a name like `MyCache` which isn't reserved.

For example:

```
var x = new MyCache(function(test) {
    return test;
});
```

Comment: @Andy this is the answer to the question. I thought about deleting the question, but thought it still had value because it shows the error which causes the given error message. If Alex K had put his comment as the answer I would have accepted it.